# Can I ask about Batch and Sed?

Tags: discussion

I'm writing a batch script that utilizes sed, but I'm having some problems with the sed part (even when I test it in a bash script with cygwin). Can I ask a question about it here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Traditional Unix command line utilities are on topic.

Comment: What about the batch component? Is that off-topic?

Comment: Windows powershell or .bat are off topic, but bash in Cygwin is probably fine.

Comment: Where do I go if my problem turns out to be batch-based?

Comment: Windows-related questions are on-topic at Super User.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is a question about your professional work environment and involves unix AND windows it might be suited for **Server Fault**.